# Remote hosted flex app

Tags: apache-flex

I have a flex app that is hosted on my server. It runs off an amfphp + mysql stack.

I have had inquiries from potential clients who want to "white label" the product. Part of this means that they would want it to appear that the app is running off their server. So their clients would login at www.theirsite.com instead of www.mysite.com.

I obviously dont want to give them the actual app...but are there ways of letting their server redirect to mine without the user actually knowing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have extensive experience with Flex, but I've worked a lot with Flash. Several ideas come to mind:

1. Create a wrapper: a SWF that loads your app. With the proper security settings, it should work. Check out [this article on crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html) and the specs for [Security.allowDomain()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Security.html)
2. You could simply embed the SWF from your site, similar to a YouTube video
3. If that is not satisfactory and your hosting services allow it, you can create a [DNS A record or a DNS C record](http://content.websitegear.com/article/subdomain_setup.htm) for a subdomain in there site, but you would support all the traffic that page has.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be for them to alter their DNS record to make a CNAME entry (alias) that is a subdomain of theirsite.com:

```
yourapp.theirsite.com => www.mysite.com
```